# Simulating a click on a page from my chrome extention

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that finds the `pageX` and `pageY` of the window, Is there is a way to fire off a click event of a targeted element, say on google if I wanted to click on the search bar once If found the correct pageX and pageY.

I want to be able to click buttons etc. from the values calculated from my extension but I cant seem to get it to work from content-scripts.js so it there a way to send the pageX and pageY to the background.js scripts.

Something like this:

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
       chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{
           code: 'document.activeElement.click()'
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simulate click events in JavaScript using the [`.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) method of the target DOM element.

It's generally easier/more meaningful to interact with a page using [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) than it is to use X, Y coordinates, but you can do so using [`document.elementFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint).

```
function clickElementAtCoordinate(x, y) {
  const el = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
  el.click();
}
``
```

Comment: I actually had to use el.focus for my case and click wont work on an input bar the way a normal mouse will, just a heads up for anyone trying to rely on click to interact with all elements on the page that are clickable.